# What is the equivalent of ng-attr-style in Angular 8?

Tags: css, angular, angular8

I've an application in AngularJS which I want to convert into Angular 8.

In the app, there is a div in which I'm passing width dynamically like this:

```
ng-attr-style="width:{{countersDtl.SurveySubmittedInstant/(countersDtl.ServiceDone)*100}}%"
```

`countersDtl` is an object with keys `SurveySubmittedInstant` and `ServiceDone`.

I've multiple elements which are using `ng-attr-style` like this only.

I've tried everything from `style.width` to `ngStyle` but nothing works.

Comment: set `ngClass` perhaps and add css there

Comment: what syntax of `ngStyle` have you tried? `ngStyle` is a correct way to do that, so maybe you've got some syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent of `ng-attr-style` is `ngStyle` binding.
You can read more about `ngStyle` in the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle).

Probably correct syntax for your case would look like this:

```
[ngStyle]="{'width': (countersDtl.SurveySubmittedInstant/(countersDtl.ServiceDone)*100) + '%'"
```

Also, you could use instead of `+ '%'` marking the property as `'width.%'`, like this:

```
[ngStyle]="{'width.%': countersDtl.SurveySubmittedInstant/(countersDtl.ServiceDone)*100"
```

And there's third possibility to bind to `width` itself, like this:

```
[style.width.%]="countersDtl.SurveySubmittedInstant/(countersDtl.ServiceDone)*100"
```